# Ubuntu 12.04 terminal only after nvidia driver upgrade

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 (after getting tired of Windows). Installation went fine.

I had one problem when I got in suspend mode and then resumed my screen was scrambled. After some googling founds some tips to upgrade my nvidia drivers. I did this, and rebooted but only a terminal windows appears now instead of a graphical desktop.

Tried to fix it by several reboots, and removing `xorg.conf`, but still no luck. Any advice how to fix it and get my desktop back ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. After you've booted, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, and login using your credentials.
2. Remove all the nVidia drivers that you installed.

   ```
   sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-*
   ```
3. Install the drivers again:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
   ```

Comment: Thanks,this did the trick! And also suspend/resume now works properly!

Comment: This worked well enough for me to get workable video drivers back onto a machine that a user had made terminal-only by loading some drivers they found out about on a gaming site.

This brought the computer back with a full desktop after an extended boot but there were immediate errors from Compiz and some other 'system problems' as well.

I fired up the driver tool and swapped from the "current driver" to the first one on the list.  Things were very snappy afterwards.

I have to ask:

Is using the x-swat repositories necessary?

Wouldn't simply reinstalling from the regular repository work?

Comment: @OlympicSoftworks-Dave I really do not know. I recomment ubuntu-x-swat because they provide stable upstream releases of X.org components.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a Terminal (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> )
2. Type this comment

   ```
   sudo unity --reset
   ```
3. Wait.
4. Restart. And you are done! :)