# 12.04 update and nvidia

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia

I've just have had nasty surprise of graphics not working after latest update (bringing it up to kernel version `3.2.0-52-generic`). Apparently after the update it was expecting `nvidia-319` driver, while it seems to me that on 12.04 `nvidia-current` points to `nvidia-304`. Thus I had to manually install `nvidia-319` and uninstall `nvidia-304`.

Is this because I've have messed up something in my configuration or is it known issue?

Comment: It happens when there are two different version of nvidia driver in the system. It is a known issue. You need to take care of the nvidia version of your kernel and the graphic card identical.

Comment: @NKN: why doesn't kernel update have that as dependency then? Or why isn't nvidia-current updated when kernel is?

Comment: I will switch to post an answer and I will update it.

Answer (score 5):

Check this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192025/ubuntu-12-04-terminal-only-after-nvidia-driver-upgrade), and similar questions first.
It happens when there are two different version of nvidia driver in the system. It is a known issue. You need to take care of the nvidia version of your kernel and the graphic card identical. 
Or,
If you didn't uninstall your previous driver version. This can happen because nvidia-current-dev is of version 304 and nvidia-current-updates-dev is of version 319 as reported.

If you've installed the nVidia driver from Ubuntu's Additional Drivers dialogue
, try

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

then try reinstalling by

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates-dev
```

then reboot. 
If you have used the .run file from nVidia's website then go to a console by pressing **Alt+Ctrl+F1** and then run

```
nvidia-xxx-pkg1.run --uninstall
```

to remove the previous driver components. Now give a reboot and see if that works. If not, then execute

```
sudo echo "blacklist nouveau" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

so that the default nouveau driver for nVidia chipsets are not loaded instead of proprietary one. Finally install packaged binary drivers by

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates-dev
```

chekc this [link](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-quetzal-nvidia.html) as well.

Comment: on 12.04, `nvidia-current` = `nvidia-current-updates` = `nvidia-304`, all of which are at version `304.88.ubuntu0.0.3`.

Comment: If you still have the problem, just uninstall everything related to nvidia and install it properly again. mine is 304.88.ubuntu0.0.2.

Comment: As I've wrote in the question, I have solved the problem manually. What I don't understand why would I have problem in the first place if I did proper update, which should have taken care of properly updating the packages.

Comment: I've had this similar issue, What I did was purge everything realted to nvidia. And did an apt-get update. Then went to Preferrences > Additional Drivers > then chose the nvidia recommended Propietary Drivers. `NVIDIA accelerated graphic driver [Recommended]`, I've chosen that option and clicked activate.  My Kernel version is `3.2.0-51-generic`

Comment: sudo echo "blacklist nouveau" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
doesn't work as sudo only elevates the echo command, not the pipe to blacklist.conf

Answer (score 4):

After you

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

try:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-319-updates-dev
```

This worked for me, without the 319 it just re installed 304.